# .htaccess URL rewrite only rerwites one page

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm rerwiting a URL to point to a different URL under the hood. But it seems like all the other files in different directories referenced by index.php (e.g. css files, JS files, etc) do not get redirected. How can I accomplish this?

I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test($|/)
RewriteRule .*$ ../index.php?orgid=4 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer is

```
RewriteRule ^(test)(.*)/?$ index.php?orgid=4 [L]
```

In the browser, this will show as example.com/test, while under the hood the url is actually example.com/index.php?orgid=4